# Using luks manager app for creating file based containers for encryption, is there any chance that unencrypted data appears in crash dumps etc?

Tags: encryption

My PC is fully encrypted and protected with TrueCrypt using. I don't use TrueCrypt encrypted file based containers as they are not safe from the OS itself. The official TrueCrypt site states that file based container encryption is insufficient because the operating system stores fragments of files and other metadata in various places in clear unencrypted form(hiberfil.sys, pagefile, crash dumps etc):

> System encryption provides the highest level of security and privacy,
>   because all files, including any temporary files that Windows and
>   applications create on the system partition (typically, without your
>   knowledge or consent), hibernation files, swap files, etc., are always
>   permanently encrypted (even when power supply is suddenly
>   interrupted). Windows also records large amounts of potentially
>   sensitive data, such as the names and locations of files you open,
>   applications you run, etc. All such log files and registry entries are
>   always permanently encrypted too.

My question is that is this a problem with android too? I have encrypted containers created with the "luks manager". One of them contains highly sensitive data, making me paranoid enough to think that the android device might also be storing file fragments and other details like windows does.

Does android have temp files, crash dumps etc?

although full device encryption is possible since honeycomb 3.0 it does not allow plausible deniability or hidden android OS etc(of course, its not useful for almost all who use Android)

Answer (score 0):

With full device encryption, unencrypted fragments should be available in volatile RAM only – which means an attacker needs physical access to the running system. There's no such thing as 100% security, but I'd say that's as close as you can get, when combining it with a good lock mechanism (best encryption is useless if you don't lock your device and an attacker can get physical access).

Als for LUKS, I'd recommend checking with [their project site](https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/), which contains a bunch of information. A raw scan (I don't use LUKS myself) even revealed information on how to use LUKS to fully encrypt partitions on the Android device. The LUKS team will also be the best address for technical details.

Comment: Feel welcome to answer your own question if you collected the details! :)